# Is there a simple way to install the Xamarin PCL profiles in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, xamarin, portable-class-library

My company is developing corporate Windows 8.1 apps for use within the organisation. Although we are only targeting Windows 8.1, we are interested in developing our apps with a view to eventually target Android and/or iOS by using Xamarin.

So, we want to develop using PCLs that are compatible with Xamarin, but we haven't licenced it yet, since we're not ready. Can we simply install the PCL profiles for Xamarin so we can at least be assured that our classes will be compatible, if and when we are ready?

Comment: You could always install the Xamarin product without registering on a trial basis. You get 30 days to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profiles are not xamarin profiles - they are .net profiles which xamarin support.

The profiles are installed as part of visual studio 2013 - or can be installed as extensions to visual studio 2012.

If you select WindowsPhone Silverlight 8.0, .net 4.5 and Windows Store apps then this will allow you to build a profile 78 pcl library - which is one of the profiles xamarin support - and is a pretty good choice for modern development...

Answer (score 1):

So you have couple of possibilities.

1. As m-y mentions in his comment you can install the trial and you will get the PCL profiles.
2. You can get someone else with the Xamarin tools installed to grab a copy of the PCL profiles on his machine (a bit harder to maintain).
3. You can buy the product (might not be what you want)

However, you could go ahead, make the PCL you are currently using and target it to WPA8.1 and Windows 8.1, and later on just change the profile and make the minor corrections it would take to get it working with Xamarin.